# Как преобразовать массив в строке в обычный массив Kotlin/?

Tags: массивы, строки, kotlin

как преобразовать такую строку, в массив

```
a = "[\"abc\",\"de\"],[\"fgi\",\"kl\"]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

1. Убираем первую скобку
2. Заменяем все скобки между элементами на запятую
3. Убираем последнюю скобку
4. Разбиваем строку на массив строк по разделителю "зяпятая"

---

```
val a = """["abc","de"],["fgi","kl"]"""
val array = a.replaceFirst("[", "").replace("],[", ",").replace("]", "").split(",")
println("array: $array")
```

Вывод:

> array: ["abc", "de", "fgi", "kl"]

Comment: А вообще - задача не вполне понятно, кажется её можно и иначе понять. Попробуйте более формально описать задачу в виде "данные на вход - данные на выход"

Comment: на вход: "["abc","de"],["fgi","kl"]"
на выход: ["abc", "de", "fgi", "kl"]
fа нет специальной функции чтобы проделать это типа literal_eval в питон или eval тоже в питоне

Comment: Компилируемые языки, как правило, не имеют функций типа eval().

Comment: спасибо, понятно